# htaccess redirect to https AND www not working

Tags: .htaccess, https

I'd like to redirect any insecure request to https, AND make sure that the url always uses 'www'. This is what I have but doesn't seem to work. What am I missing?

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly.

Comment: As this answer solved your problem, [you should mark the answer as accepted by clicking on **tick mark** on top-left of this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/160242) Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

```
## Redirecting HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

## Redirecting non WWW to WWW
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.tld$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.tld/$1 [R=301,L]
```